# Populate nested references in Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a collection 'users' and a collection 'posts'. Each user has a list of references to their published posts.

Whenever I retrieve a user, I need to see their posts plain data but they act like raw references instead of showing just the documents' data.

Right now I have one user that has posted many posts. So the field 'posts' inside the user's doc is an Array of references to the posts themselves. I retrieve the user's data and this is returned:

```
username: "TestUsername",
posts: [
    DocumentReference {
      _firestore: [Firestore],
      _path: [ResourcePath],
      _converter: [Object]
    },
    DocumentReference {
      _firestore: [Firestore],
      _path: [ResourcePath],
      _converter: [Object]
    },
    DocumentReference {
      _firestore: [Firestore],
      _path: [ResourcePath],
      _converter: [Object]
    }
  ],
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Firebase does not automatically load the documents that you reference from the other collection. You will have to do this yourself in your application code.

So once the user document is loaded, you can loop over their `posts` field and then load each `DocumentReference` in turn.

Alternatively you can change your data model to:

- *either* also store the user ID in each post, and then load all posts for a specific user in one go by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries),
- *or* you can store the posts for each user in a subcollection under their user document, and load them from there. If you do this, you can still get/query all posts for all users by using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: I already save the user ID in each post, how could I load all posts for a specific user in one go but seeing the correct data of each post?

Comment: That would be with a query: I added a link to the docs for that too, but it'd be something like `db.collection("posts").where("userID", "==", "uidOfUserYouWant")`. If you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to show [the minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey @JMRBDev Anything else needed here?